# Access property value from array in reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm unable to render the `name` property value in my `editProductBasket` array.

When I console log `editProductBasket`, I get `undefined` even though I clearly dispatched the action.

First, I send a dispatch to my reducer that sets the array to my store:

```js
dispatch({
                type: "SET_EDIT_PRODUCTS",
                item: [
                  {
                    name: productData.name,
                    price: productData.price,
                    description: productData.description,
                    quantity: productData.description,
                  },
                ],
              });
```

My console log of the dispatch prints the following:

[Console Log Of My Dispatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaH2P.png)

Here is how I am storing the dispatch in my reducer:

```js
export const initialState = {
  editProductBasket: [],
};
```

And here is the structure of my case:

```js
case "SET_EDIT_PRODUCT":
      return {
        ...state,
        editProductBasket: [...state.editProductBasket, ...action.item],
      };
```

Now, in my component I try to render the `name` property from the `editBasketProduct` array:

```js
const [{ editProductBasket }, dispatch] = useStateValue();


 return (
    <div className="phone__mockup">
      <h1>{editProductBasket.name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: It seems, you have more than 1 item in your editProductBasket array in the state. It says undefined because there is nothing like editProductBasket.name, but there may be editProductBasket[0].name, editProductBasket[1].name and so on... So I think you should use an iterator when you try to render the part of the state. For ex: you can use Array.map() or  Array.foreach in your code when returning/rendering items.

Comment: @sibumi Thanks for your help! I'm still getting `name: undefined`